# Connecting to a Ghost User in Flex RTMFP

Tags: apache-flex, rtmfp

I have a simple Flex RTMFP P2P video app in the same mold as the [Adobe Cirrus VideoPhone Sample application](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/samples/). A problem I've been encountering in developing this app (the same problem occurs in the sample) is when you try to connect to a ghost Stratus instance i.e you try to call someone whose Stratus id is in the database but who is no longer on the page. So here's an example of what I mean:

Let's say you go to the Adobe Stratus sample and connect as Dan. Then open up a new tab, go to the sample again and connect as Fred. If from this point, you (as Fred) call Dan everything will work fine. But, if you close the tab in which you connected as Dan, and then from the Fred tab try to connect to Dan the program will just hang.

I would have thought there would be a NetStream event that would be triggered if you tried to connect to a Stratus instance that is not longer online but I can't seem to find anything besides NetStream.Connect.Rejected which doesn't seem to be called.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `NetStream.Connect.Failed`?

You should also add an event listener to the incoming stream and watch for the `NetStream.Connect.Closed` to see if it is disconnected during conversation. If it is fired any time; remove that peer from your db.